# Python - Classe CTR não registra no DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mvc, sqlalchemy

Boa noite.

**Aplicação desenvolvida em Python 3.x**
**Banco de dados:** sqlalchemy.
Estou tentando desenvolver um simples sistema de registro de produtos em um banco de dados SQL.
Para tanto, estou tentando desenvolver a partir do Padrão MVC (Model, View e Controller).
Nesse sentido, criei as classes da forma que achei que estivessem corretas (conforme arquivo do projeto).
O problema está ocorrendo dentro da classe ProdutoCTR.

'''ProdutosDAO'''
from DataBase.database import ConexaoDB
from DataBase.database import Tabelas

class ProdutosDAO:

```
def prod_Cadastrar(produto):
    # Conexão
    conexaoDB = ConexaoDB()
    db = conexaoDB.db()
    meta = conexaoDB.meta()

    # Tabelas
    table = Tabelas()
    prodTable = table.prod_Table()

    # Inserir no DB
    db.excute(prodTable.insert(), [{'prod_Desc': produto.prod_Desc,
                                    'prod_Unid': produto.prod_Unid,
                                    'prod_VrUnit': produto.prod_VrUnit}])
```

**
Módulo controller
**

```
from Model.DTO.produtosDTO import ProdutosDTO
from Model.DAO.produtosDAO import ProdutosDAO


class ProdutosCTR:

    def prod_Cadastrar(self, prod_Desc, prod_Unid, prod_VrUnit):
        produtoDTO = ProdutosDTO()
        produtoDTO.prod_Desc = prod_Desc
        produtoDTO.prod_Unid = prod_Unid
        produtoDTO.prod_VrUnit = prod_VrUnit

        produtoDAO = ProdutosDAO()
        produtoDAO.prod_Cadastrar(produtoDTO)
```

Como é possível notar, nesta classe a função prod_Cadastrar() do objeto produtoDAO recebe como parâmetro o produtoDTO, cujos atributos foram preenchidos na interface:

**
Interface
**

```
from Controller.produtosCTR import ProdutosCTR


class Interface:

    def prod_Cadastrar(self):
        prodCTR = ProdutosCTR()
        desc = self.prod_CadDesc()
        unid = self.prod_CadUnid()
        vr_unit = self.prod_CadVrUnit()
        prodCTR.prod_Cadastrar(desc, unid, vr_unit)

    def prod_CadDesc(self):
        self.descricao = str(input('Descrição: ')).upper()
        return self.descricao

    def prod_CadUnid(self):
        self.unid = str(input('Unidade: ')).upper()
        return self.unid

    def prod_CadVrUnit(self):
        self.valorUnit = float(input('Valor Unitário: '))
        return self.valorUnit
```

Ao tentar executar o código aparece o seguinte erro:

> "C:\Users\theu_\PycharmProjects\Melon v.
>   0.0.1\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/theu_/PycharmProjects/Melon v. 0.0.1/main.py" Descrição: Matheus Unidade: kg Valor Unitário: 10
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/theu_/PycharmProjects/Melon v. 0.0.1/main.py", line 7, in
>   
>       int.prod_Cadastrar()   File "C:\Users\theu_\PycharmProjects\Melon v. 0.0.1\View\interface.py", line 14, in prod_Cadastrar
>       prodCTR.prod_Cadastrar(desc, unid, vr_unit)   File "C:\Users\theu_\PycharmProjects\Melon v.
>   0.0.1\Controller\produtosCTR.py", line 18, in prod_Cadastrar
>       produtoDAO.prod_Cadastrar(produtoDTO)
>   **TypeError: prod_Cadastrar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

alguém pode me ajudar a entender o problema?
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Pelo erro está claro que na classe `ProdutosDTO` você definiu o método `prod_Cadastrar` com um número de argumentos, mas quando você o invoca, passa outro número. Revise isso.

Comment: Acho que você quis dizer ProdutosDAO. Nesse caso, fiz a edição da pergunta e adicionei a classe citada. Se puder dar uma olhada. Grato.

Comment: Faltou o argumento `self` ou definir o método como estático.